# After installing latest SSMS, error only when creating database diagram

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration, database-diagram

Perhaps it's coincidental, since I very rarely do DBA, but after installing the latest SSMS yesterday I tried to create a database diagram for a database and received the following error:

> Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'AzureAD\UserId'

I am the owner of the database and one of the role members for sysadmin.  I can create databases, delete them, add tables, back up and restore them, etc., but for some reason I can't create a database diagram.  I'm nearly clueless when it comes to DBA, so be gentle.

Comment: Here are the version numbers:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 13.0.16000.28; Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 13.0.1700.441; Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 10.0.14393.0; Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0; Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.11.14393.0; Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000; Operating System 6.3.14393

Comment: Maybe duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845836/could-not-obtain-information-about-windows-nt-group-user   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234570/could-not-obtain-information-about-windows-nt-group-user

Comment: Thanks Ahmed.  I already looked at both posts.  I tried the solution in the first one to the best of my knowledge (which is very little).  I think the owner of the DB is correct and the permissions are fine.  I can perform all sorts of operations without problems.

Regarding the second post, I don't know what STAR domain controller is.

I did run across this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00ced01b-0a5b-47f4-9c55-2dc62be16863/sql-server-2016-susersname-problem-with-microsoft-account?forum=sqlsecurity) after posting.  There may be some bug running around.